# Load HTML Page In Textarea

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, load

I've been trying to load a html document into a textarea when the page loads.

I know you can use the ajax load api in JQuery...

```
$("#siteloader").load('startup.html');
```

but if I try to load this into the textarea...

```
var mirror = $("#pageloader"),
    input = $("#pagecode");

input.val(mirror.load('startup.html'));
```

I get `[object Object]` which I figured wouldn't work, but thought I'd try it anyway as I just didn't know if it would work or not.

Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(function () {
    function download_to_textbox(url, el) {
        $.get(url, null, function (data) {
            el.val(data);
        }, "text");
    }
    download_to_textbox("startup.html", $("#textareaID"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try this one:

```
input.val(mirror.load('startup.html').html());
```