# I want to load text dynamically in a text box from a unix shell using jQuery/AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, shell

I am developing an application where in I give some inputs in a HTML form and those inputs are propogated to a shell program. A of now I am able to display the output from the shell program in another webpage once Submit is clicked. I want to to display the content in the same page in a text box or some other way. I heard that i need to use jQuery or AJAX to do this. What is the best way to do that?

PS: The output of the shell Program is huge. The text box should display everything as its displayed on the console.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18546334/1707033 - something like this maybe?

Comment: Send an AJAX request to a page that runs the shell script via a server-side language (like PHP). Then have the page spit out the results as the AJAX response, which you can then display on your page.